# How to store one value using core-data ? (swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

I'm developing an app to store one phone number at time using core data, the user should be able to enter a new phone number into ui text field,if it's equal to nil, it should store a new phone number,else it should replace old number with new number; it should store only one value.

but the code doesn't work as it should

what's wrong in my code?

```
  let moContext: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context: NSManagedObjectContext = moContext.managedObjectContext
            let phoneNu = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Setting", inManagedObjectContext: context)


            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Setting")
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumber = %@", phoneNumber)
           // phoneNu.setValue(phoneNumber.text, forKey: "phoneNumber")



            do{
                let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Setting")
                let phoneN = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
                if phoneN.count == 0{
                    phoneNu.setValue(phoneNumber.text, forKey: "phoneNumber")
                }else if phoneN.count != 0{
                  for item in phoneN as! [NSManagedObject]{

                    let number = item.valueForKey("phoneNumber")
                    number?[0]?.setValue(phoneNumber.text, forKey: "phoneNumber")
                    }
                }
            }catch{

                print("error")

            }


            do{

                let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Setting")
                let phoneNumber = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

                if phoneNumber.count > 0{
                    for item in phoneNumber as! [NSManagedObject]{

                        let number = item.valueForKey("phoneNumber")

                        print(number!)
                    }
                }


            }catch{

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution

```
let moContext: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = moContext.managedObjectContext

guard let phoneNumber = phoneNumber.text where phoneNumber.characters.count > 0 else {
    return// returns if textField is empty.
}

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Setting")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumber = %@", phoneNumber)

do{
   let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Setting")
   let phoneObjectArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

   guard let settingFetched = phoneObjectArray as? [Setting] where settingFetched.count > 0 else {
    // if enters here -> 0 phone numbers were found

       if let setting = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Setting", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? Setting {
        setting.phoneNumber = phoneNumber

        // call context.save()
       }

    return // this I forgot
   }

let settingObject = settingFetched.first

// fetch results return store phone number.
// update phone number
settingObject.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
// call context.save()

} catch let error as NSError! {
  print("error: \(error)")

}
```

You need to call the "save()" function to persist the information.

I did some changes to the name variables, added some validations and assume some model class name based on your code. 
I always recommend to use your NSManagedObject subclass (Setting I assume) instead of just using NSManagedObject and key/value coding.

There could be some minor syntax mistakes on the code because I was using a text editor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 2 errors have appeared,

the first error at line 5 says "Non-void function should return a value"

the second error at line 15 says "Use of unresolved identifier 'setting'"

Comment: I think you aren't implementing correctly the code... Let me try to help you. in the return inside the "guard" you just return nothing. If the function is a Void function (function() {}) this just get you out of the method. As for the second error, did you use "if setting" or "if let setting" ?

Comment: I've put the code inside `textFieldShouldReturn` method, so when the user press on keyboard's return button, it inserts data into data base

about the second error, I used "if let setting"

Comment: The return should then have a true or false value (depending of what you want the return button to do). As for the other error, I forgot to add the return on the `guard`. My bad. See the edit.

Comment: sorry for causing you headache

but I'm still facing one error in the code

at line 15 `guard let settingFetched = Setting.first else` ,the error still says "Use of unresolved identifier setting"

,I think this line below could solve the problem, right?

`let Setting =  try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [SettingData]`

Comment: Don't worry, it was acutally my mistake, is supossed to be  `guard let settingFetched = phoneObjectArray.first else`.

Comment: your code almost just fine, there's just one problem.

I'm starting to get the feeling I am an annoying person :P

at line 28 `settingFetched.phoneNumber = phoneNumber` an error has appeared and it says "Ambiguous reference to member 'phoneNumber'", however I removed that line and the code work great, it take just one value but I can't update it

Comment: Just edited my answer, this should be fine. I were missing some variables (for doing it in a textEdit). But now should work.

Comment: let me tell you're awesome :)

Comment: Glad I was able to hel! Please, if your problem was solves,  mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, Core Data is overkill.

Use `NSUserDefaults` instead. So much easier.

Comment: I'm kinda naive in iOS development, so I don't understand how `NSUserDefaults` could solve my problem.

could it help me to do what I want to do ?

Comment: Just look up the class reference, it's super simple.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11026304)

Comment: @Abubakr Dar. No, in fact it is the best solution to the OP's problem. He want's to squash a fly by using cannons. I am telling him to use a more wieldy tool. What is your expertise to make this call?

Comment: Your answer's essence might be right but surely its not enough. Maybe if you point out why he shouldn't use Coredata and use NSUserDefaults instead. You should if possible, also mention the shortcomings of UserDefaults.

Comment: @Mundi your solution is great somehow, however I'm developing two different apps for two different systems,Android and iOS; my apps should be developed based on ERD diagram, so I can't use default database.